# How to know number of labels and textfields present in the scrollview by program?

Tags: ios

I took a scrollview and i am adding labels dynamically which looks like this

```
for(int tempvariable=0; tempvariable<n;tempvariable++)
{
   CGRect labelFrame2 = CGRectMake(  x3,y3, 20, 20 );
   UILabel *label3=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelFrame2];
   [subview addSubview:label3];
}

[self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
```

`"n"` is the dynamic value after adding the label n times to the subview I have added the subview to the scrollview. Now I want to print all the titles of the labels present on the scrollview in `NSLog(@'");`

If I want to change some titles of labels than how can i do that only through scrollview without subview?

Comment: the index of the center label is `scrollView.contentOffset.x / label.frame.size.width`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIView *subview in self.scrollView.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel* l=(UILabel)subview;
        NSLog(@"%@",l.text);
        l.text=@"new title";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the tag to find the label which you want to change the label text..

```
for(int tempvariable=0; tempvariable<n;tempvariable++)
{
   CGRect labelFrame2 = CGRectMake(  x3,y3, 20, 20 );
   UILabel *label3=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelFrame2];
   label3.tag = tempVariable;

// you can set the label text here..
   [subview addSubview:label3];
}
```

as @tillerstarr mentioned in his answer you can iterate your subviews to get the text of the labels.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.scrollView.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        if (subview.tag == 5) {
             UILabel* l=(UILabel)subview;
             // you can check the tag value and change the label title as like this
             l.text=@"fifth label";
          }
    }
}
```